# Crop Image swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, crop

I am using [CropImg](https://github.com/DuncanMC/CropImg) this link to Crop image in swift. All the things are working fine. but I have one silly question. In this **CropppableImageView** class has delegate named CropDelegate. I have taken one view in my viewController and then I use the "Idenity Inspector" to change the type to CroppableImageView. but I am not able to connect CropDelegate with my viewController.

Can anyone guide me to do this? I know this is very silly question but I am not able to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CropDelegate
```

and then set the delegate via

```
imageView.cropDelegate = self
```

Comment: But if I want to connect that delegate using storyboard than how can I do that?

Comment: then you have to drag that view to controller and you can see the property you can bind there in storyboard

Comment: I am trying to do that.. I have assign in "Idenity Inspector" the viewcontroller's name

Comment: than what is the issue ma'am?

Comment: I am not able to show the selected image because my this delegate is not assigned.

Comment: please try via code as I can't tell you without seeing storyboard

Comment: ma'am you have approved not upvoted that's why I asked